# "admit" vs "admit of"

Tags: difference, formal-language

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/admit?q=admit:

> `3.` [with object] Accept as valid:
>
> `4.` [no object] (admit of) Allow the possibility of:

What are the similarities and differences? Aren't 3 and 4 equivalent:
Something is accepted as valid, but NOT necessarily accepted with finality
<=> something is an allowable/valid possibility?

In the following example, doesn't "The question is too general
to **admit** one answer" mean alike?

> The question is too general
> to **admit of** one answer.

Source: p 98, Ward Farnsworth

Comment: The question is too general to admit of one answer = This question is too general and it cannot have one answer. *admit one...* won't work here. Both are entirely different - *admit something (with direct object)* and *admit of (no direct object)*. The previous means accepted as valid and the latter *introduces* the possibilities

Comment: Meaning 3 is just about _never_ heard outside court, I think. Look at the examples that are given. I would not assume anyone would understand what you mean if you use admit in that sense outside of court. For the admitting (of) one answer, the version with _admit of_ indicates that it is not acceptable to assume only _one answer_ will be correct. The version _without of_ indicates that for some reason a court will not accept one answer as valid evidence in a case _unless there are also other answers_. That sounds ridiculous...

Comment: From the OED: "**I.2.d.** With *subord. clause.* To allow, concede, grant (either from conviction, or for the sake of argument). ¶In these senses *admit* is sometimes followed by *of*."  Personally, I think *admit of* sounds rather archaic or jargon-y.

Comment: @MaulikV Thanks. Does your comment contradict Nico's answer below, though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Merriam–Webster's Dictionary of English Usage (MWDEU)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merriam%E2%80%93Webster%27s_Dictionary_of_English_Usage) has an entry for *'admit of'*. It quotes Fowler (1926) pointing out *"that the combination 'admit of' is more limited in application than it once was and that **it usually takes a nonhuman subject**"* (emphasis mine).

MWDEU lists the following examples of use with a nonhuman subject:

> [...] questions which, by their very nature, **admit of** no satifactory answer
> <sub>(R. A. Posner, *New Republic*, 21 Aug. 2000)</sub>
>
> They content that many words are absolutes that do not **admit of** comparison
> <sub>(Bernstein, 1971)</sub>
>
> The rule [...] **admitted of** some justification
> <sub>(W. Raspberry, *Springfield (Mass.) Union News*, 20 Jan. 1989)</sub>
>
> The problems of ecology [...] **admit of** rational solution
> <sub>(A. Huxley, *Center Mag.*, Sept. 1969)</sub>
>
> It is a judgement that **admits of** no excuses
> <sub>(B. Ehrenreich, *N.Y. Times Book Rev.*, 14 Oct. 1990)</sub>

and the following example of the rare usage with a personal subject:

> But even they will **admit of** a number of amusing eccentricities
> <sub>(S. Winchester, *The Professor and the Madman*, 1989)</sub>

---

Hence, to answer the OP's question, both sentences:

> The question is too general to **admit** one answer.
> The question is too general to **admit of** one answer.

have essentially the same meaning. Although the latter version is rarer, it has, as Fowler points out, a nonhuman subject.

Answer (score 0):

> The question is too general to admit one answer

That doesn't sound right to me. I don't think anyone would say it like that. A question can't admit anything. To admit something is to let that thing in, to allow it entry. You need some agent to do the admitting. A question can't admit an anwer, and if it could, into where would it be admitting the answer?

As oerkelens pointed, meaning #3 is mostly—if not exclusively—to do with courts of law. A court can admit something as evidence. Or admit it into evidence, as they say.

> The question is too general to admit of one answer.

*Admit of* is pretty rare and would only be used in very formal writing.